# Meaning of the word Abstract

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, linguistics

Recently I came across with a word called **abstraction** in mathematics which means the process of removing unimportant details from a system so that we can focus on the ones that really matter.

I found this notion of the word abstraction to be very different than what abstract means in daily English language usage - something that exists only in thought, something that cannot be touched.

This confused me. What exactly do we mean by abstract? Are these two meanings completely independent, or is there a sense in which one overarches the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phenomenology of abstraction](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/phenomenology-of-abstraction)
(or one of the many more articles on the subject)

Comment: The classic "assume a spherical cow" (or "assume the cow is roughly spherical") evidences both meanings of "abstraction" you recite in your question -- the "can exist only in thought" and "removing unnecessary details" meanings. It's a spoof of that kind of abstraction, a running gag in physics circles.

Comment: The two definitions are roughly the same. If you think about a particular horse, then that horse exists out in the world. If you think about an abstract horse (throwing away any concept of color or location for example) then that abstract horse exists only in your mind.

Answer (score 2):

[Abstraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction)

> Abstraction in its main sense is a conceptual process wherein general rules and concepts are derived from the usage and classification of specific examples, literal ("real" or "concrete") signifiers, first principles, or other methods.

> "An abstraction" is the outcome of this process—a concept that acts as a common noun for all subordinate concepts and connects any related concepts as a group, field, or category. ~ Wikipedia

That's only an excerpt from the introduction.

Things that exist only in the mind I guess can be found in pure as opposed to applied math.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused because you've conflated different parts of speech.

- The *adjective* 'abstract' is a modifier meaning conceptual, idealized, or theoretical.
- The *verb* 'to abstract' means to make something more general and universal by removing specific, concrete details
- The *noun* abstract* is a summary of a paper containing only the key points, without any of the details of research or reasoning.

'Abstraction' is the noun-form of the verb 'to abstract', effectively: "That which has been abstracted (made more general and universal)". Not everything that is an *abstraction* has the quality (1°) of being *abstract*, but in mathematics everything is fairly *abstract* to begin with.

I mean, honestly, this is a bit like getting confused about the word 'object' because you learned the word 'objection'. Language use is organic, and thus not entirely reasoned.